# Where is the Data Contract for a WCF Data Service?

Tags: wcf-data-services

I've been trying to a Windows Forms client to get data from a WCF Data Service that is secured with Custom Basic Authentication. My problem is that after successfully authenticating the client, either the WCF Data Service does not return the requested data, or the client does not receive it somehow.

I've looked around and seen that home have suggested the use of BasicHttpBinding. So I've set it up on the WCF Data service. However, I don't know what to put inside contract

This is because I don't have a Data Contract in the WCF Data Service, unlike a normal WCF application where you have the files IService and Service.

Comment: How did you create client stub for WCF Data Service and how do you call it (show some code).